# Spock throws MissingMethodException on dynamic method that is not presented in interface

Tags: grails, groovy, spock

I have  groovy.lang.GroovyObject interface which is extended. Implementor class does not have a public constructor and contains dynamic method that are not presented in inteface.

I'm trying to do this:

```
def bean = Stub(GroovyObject)
bean.getResults() >> ['result1', 'results2']
```

while invoking:

```
bean.getResults()
```

it would throw groovy.lang.MissingMethodException.
In fact I do not carry about interface contract, I merely need to make sure stubed object returns expected list.

Also I cannot stub implementor class, it would throw CannotCreateMockException.

Comment: Do you have a runnable example that shows the failure?

Comment: try to run this in a Specification test
def bean = Stub(GroovyObject)
bean.getResults() >> ['result1', 'results2']
bean.getResults() 
You will get No signature of method .... @Tim

Comment: What is the class/interface you're trying to stub out?  Why are you stubbing GroovyObject instead of your interface?

Comment: I do not have interface. In fact end object is a GroovyMBean which binds methods in runtime based on what comes from jmx @tim_yates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I have eventually found a solution myself.

Instead of Stub GroovyStub has to be used. That would allow no to do verification against methods of stubed class. Also GroovyObject interface didn't work, had to use GroovyObjectSupport abstract class:

```
def bean = GroovyStub(GroovyObjectSupport) 
bean.getResults() >> ['result1', 'results2']
assert bean.getResults() == ['result1', 'results2']
```